# Using dynamic terrain in cesium?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, terrain, cesium, dynamic-layer

I've been looking into tools for displaying dynamic terrain (x,y,z(t)) via the browser and I just recently came across `cesium.js` which looks like a wonderful tool at first glance. Many of the demos show static terrain which is great, but the data sets I'll be working with are all dynamic. My original plan was to do this with `three.js` and `d3.js` but after looking at `cesium.js`, I would say, "I'd be reinventing the wheel" (which would likely come out square).

I read up on the `quantized-mesh` and it sounds like the mesh is optimized based on the elevation. While that results in an optimized user experience for static displays, changing the height would require a recalculation of the mesh, which is practically of no use for continuous dynamic visualizations.

If  `cesium.js` does not support dynamic terrain of the form (x,y,z(t)) out of the box, what processes would I have to perform to display it through `cesium.js`?

Comment: Cesium uses [Quantized Mesh](https://cesiumjs.org/data-and-assets/terrain/formats/quantized-mesh-1.0.html) for terrain, which does not support animated terrain.  You can have [animated polygons](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=CZML%20Polygon%20-%20Interpolating%20References.html&label=All) on top of terrain, or swap out one terrain set with another one every so often.  It depends how rapidly or fluidly your terrain needs to change, is it time intervals or more continuous?  Try to post a single question with specific details of what is needed.